# SVG Element, HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm Creating a SVG elements but I want to make it clickable and change the color of it on click

Here's the code of the elements

```
<svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="960px"
 height="560px" viewBox="0 0 960 560" style="disable-background:new 0 0 960 560;" xml:space="preserve">

<g id="Layer_1">
      <rect x="95.675" y="35.61" class="st0" width="774.026" height="494.805"/>
  </g>
<g id="Layer_2">
      <circle class="st1" cx="254.766" cy="144.67" r="68.182"/>
      <circle class="st1" cx="474.571" cy="144.67" r="68.182"/>
      <circle class="st1" cx="685.766" cy="144.67" r="68.182"/>
      <ellipse class="st1" cx="474.571" cy="318.727" rx="167.695" ry="76.623"/>
      <circle class="st1" cx="324.748" cy="463.532" r="47.403"/>
      <circle class="st1" cx="477.565" cy="463.532" r="47.403"/>
      <circle class="st1" cx="624.395" cy="463.532" r="47.403"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an example: changing an element's color on click:

```
$('#Layer_1').click( function() {
    $('#Layer_1').css({ fill: "blue" });
});
```

You can build you idea from this.
Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/bcLzp929/1/